# Let L be a language over {a,b} that contains the same number of occurrences of a and b. Which of the following language is regular?

Tags: regular-language, nsregularexpression, computation-theory, gate

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU278.png)

Why option C is also not correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: Option C is not correct because it includes strings of the form `b^na^n`. Basically, unless the string is in the form `a*b*`, it is guaranteed to have the same number of `a`s as `b`s, and those strings are not regular.

Answer (score 0):

Let's evaluate each one in turn. Let L be the language over {a, b} with #a = #b.

(a) L intersect a*b*. This is the language of strings of the form a^n b^n. This is not regular by the Myhill-Nerode theorem since each string a^k has a unique shortest string b^k which can be appended to get a string in the language, and there are clearly infinitely many such cases, so there can be no finite automaton for the language.

(b) (L intersect a*b*) union a*b*. This is regular because (L intersect a*b*) is clearly a subset of a*b*, but the union of a subset with any of its supersets is the superset; thus, (L intersect a*b*) union a*b* = a*b* which is regular since it has just three unique equivalence classes: those strings which can be followed by a*b* to get a string in the language; those that can only be followed by b* to get a string in the language; and those strings which cannot be followed by anything to get a string in the language.

(c) L union a*b*. This is not regular because strings of the form b^(k+1)a have unique shortest strings a^k which can be appended to get a string in the language, and there are clearly infinitely many such cases, so there can be no finite automaton to cover them all.

(d) (L intersect a*b*) union b*a*. This is not regular because strings of the form a^(k+1)b have unique shortest strings b^k which can be appended to get strings in the language, and there are infinitely many such cases, so no finite automaton can cover them all.